# Step by step animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to apply four states as animation to an element using CSS.

My sample code:

```css
.child {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #068031;
}

#main-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: Step_by_step_movement 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes Step_by_step_movement {

    0% {
        top: 0%;
        left: 0;
    }

    50% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 15%;
    }

    100% {
        top: 20%;
        left: 25%;
    }

    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }


    0% {
        top: 20%;
        left: 25%; 
    }

    50% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 15%;
    }

    100% {
        top: 0%;
        left: 0;
    }


    from {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }

}
```

```html
<div id="main-box">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The problem with the above code is that only two animations are executed simultaneously.

Is there a way to use CSS to run an animation at a specific time each time and then run the next animation immediately after it ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want to:

1. Move the element from `(0%, 0%)` to `(20%, 25%)` and then back to `(0%, 0%)`.
2. Rotate the element around the `Y-axis` and then around the `X-axis`.

With infinite

```css
.child {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #068031;
}

#main-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: combinedAnimation 9s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes combinedAnimation {
  /* Move sequence */
  0%,
  22.22% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  5.55% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
  }
  11.11% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 25%;
  }
  16.66% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
  }
  22.22% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  /* RotateY sequence */
  22.23%,
  44.44% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  44.44% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  /* RotateX sequence */
  44.45%,
  66.66%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  66.66% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
CSS with infinite:
<div id="main-box">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Without infinite

```css
.child {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #068031;
}

#main-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* Apply multiple animations with delays */
  animation: move 3s linear 0s forwards, rotateY 3s linear 3s forwards, /* This starts right after 'move' ends */
  rotateX 3s linear 6s forwards;
  /* This starts right after 'rotateY' ends */
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 25%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateY {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateX {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
CSS without infinite:
<div id="main-box">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your very good answer. Yes, that's what I wanted. Only after completing the four modes, can the animation be repeated infinitely in the same way?

Comment: I have added 2 css. One with infinite and another one without infinite. If you found this answer helpful please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great code you wrote.

Comment: You’re very welcome. I’m glad I was able to help.